# Converting string to XML

Tags: c#, linq

I 've written a Query with Linq and in one part of my code I try to assign string to an XML but an error occured:

**Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'**

This is my code:

```
public int Save(Route route)
{            
     aspnetdbDataContext aspdb = new aspnetdbDataContext();
     RouteLinq rtlq=new RouteLinq();
     rtlq.UserId = route.UserId;
     rtlq.SourceName = route.Name;

     //I have an error hier
     rtlq.GpxData = route.GpxData;
     //---------------------------
     rtlq.CreationTime = route.Time;
     aspdb.RouteLinqs.InsertOnSubmit(rtlq);
     aspdb.SubmitChanges();
}
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Which item is the `XElement`?

Comment: rtlq.GpxData ia an XML,I'm not able to use `Tostring()`

Comment: You should be using [`XElement.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb468714.aspx) to make it work

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is rtlq.GpxData an `string` containing Xml or an `XElement`?  Also, you say you want to assign Xml (`XElement`?) to a `string`, but the error message says the opposite. And why can't you use `ToString()`?

Comment: Oh sorry ,that was my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because GpxData is of type XML in your database you can't assign string to it directly, you need to create an en XElement and then assign it the value:

```
rtlq.GpxData = new XElement(route.GpxData);
```

Where `route.GpxData` is of type string

Answer (score 1):

if you have an XElement, you can get just the text content like this:

```
string content = someXElement.Value
```

If you want the complete node, you need to use `XElement.ToString()`.

**UPDATE:** After your latest edit it's more clear you actually want a new XElement:

```
rtlq.GpxData = new XElement("GpxData", route.GpxData);
```

The first parameter is the name of the node, the second is the content. If `route.GpxData` already contains an Xml string, you can also use `XElement.Parse(route.GpxData)`